# How to change the base type of a UDT in Sql Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-defined-types

I have my type "x" of type varchar(50). **How can I alter it to varchar(100)?** It seems I can't!

Comment: insanity! I am now just realizing the db I am working on is ALL UDT..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can't.
what you can do is

- script all objects that contain the type using OBJECT_DEFINITION.
- drop them.
- recreate type with new length
- recreate the objects.

Comment: Correct. There is "CREATE TYPE" and "DROP TYPE" but no "ALTER TYPE".

Comment: You can vote for "ALTER TYPE" syntax on https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/319134/msft-mso-support-alter-type

Comment: Wow, it's been a decade since you wrote that and UDTs still can't be altered.