# Convert Varchar value to Hash:varchar

Tags: sql-server

I'm in the process of migrating data,when i tried to migrate the data running sql scripts, i'm getting the "String or binary data would be truncated" error. I checked my code and found that 1 column in the source table has Varchar value of 512 and the destination table has a Hash:varchar value of 128.

How do i convert varchar value to Hash:varchar so i can transferred the data.
Source Column: CardHash varchar(512)
Destination Column: CardNumberHash Hash:varchar(128)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert `varchar` to `Hash:varchar`;  `Hash:varchar` is a user defined type, and you'll need to modify it to `varchar(512)`.

Unfortunately, you cannot alter the type directly.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383494/alter-user-defined-type-in-sql-server/1383509#1383509) for a way to create a new type and update your destination table to use it.