# SQL - how to refresh metadata on a User Defined Table Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-types

I need to change the datatype of a User Defined Data Type (UDDT). I'm using [this strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383509/468871) of renaming the old UDDT and creating a new one with the orignal name. This means that any stored procedures and views will continue to work after they've been refreshed using:

```
EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule '{objectName}'
```

On columns I still have to call ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN and drop and recreate any indexes but it's relatively low-risk and scriptable.

The problem I have now is with User Defined Table Types (UDTT) that use the UDDT. The code for them won't have changed but I somehow need to get the db to refresh them so the the reference will pass onto the new UDDT and I can drop the old one. Is there anything like sp_refreshsqlmodule that will do this? I really don't want to have to drop and recreate each UDTT...