# Refresh table type when underlying UDT is changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to increase length of a User Data Type. I am following below approach:

1. rename data type to _old
2. create the data type with same name but with increased length.
3. executing sp_refreshsqlmodule for the SPs and FNs which are referencing that.

I could not think how to handle the User Defined Table Types because their meta cannot be updated with sp_refreshsqlmodule. There are so many of them and I cannot write drop and create for each of the table types manually.

Searched may posts but no success so if you have any ideas please post your answers. A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013201/sql-how-to-refresh-metadata-on-a-user-defined-table-type) was asked but no answer.

I am posting a code snippet for reference. 
Thank you.

```
/****** DROP OBJECTS ******/
IF(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test_SP',N'P') IS NOT NULL)
  DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Test_SP
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.table_types WHERE name = 'TestTableType' AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo'))
  DROP TYPE dbo.TestTableType
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.types WHERE name = 'TestType_Old' AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo'))
  DROP TYPE dbo.TestType_Old
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.types WHERE name = 'TestType' AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo'))
  DROP TYPE dbo.TestType
GO
/**************************/

CREATE TYPE dbo.TestType FROM VARCHAR(30) NULL
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.TestTableType AS TABLE (FullName dbo.TestType )
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test_SP (@FullName dbo.TestType)
AS
(
  SELECT  @FullName
)
GO

DECLARE @FN dbo.TestType

SET @FN = REPLICATE('A',30)

EXEC dbo.Test_SP  @FullName = @FN
GO


EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.TestType'
              ,N'TestType_Old'
              ,N'USERDATATYPE'
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.TestType FROM VARCHAR(60) NULL
GO

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT  sch.name + N'.' + obj.name
FROM    sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
        INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
          ON sed.referencing_id = obj.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch WITH(NOLOCK)
          ON sch.schema_id = obj.schema_id
WHERE   referenced_class_desc = 'TYPE' 
        AND referenced_entity_name IN(N'TestType',N'TestType_Old')
        AND referenced_schema_name = N'dbo'
UNION
SELECT  sch.name + N'.' + obj.name [ObjectName]
FROM    sys.columns col WITH(NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN sys.objects obj WITH(NOLOCK)
          ON col.object_id = obj.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.types typ WITH(NOLOCK)
          ON col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch WITH(NOLOCK)
          ON obj.schema_id = sch.schema_id
WHERE   typ.name IN(N'TestType',N'TestType_Old')
        AND typ.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo')
        AND is_ms_shipped = 0
        AND obj.type IN(N'TF','FS', 'IF');

OPEN cur;

DECLARE @ObjectName NVARCHAR(MAX);

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ObjectName;
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
  PRINT @ObjectName;
  EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule @name = @ObjectName;
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ObjectName;
END;

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
GO

DECLARE @FN dbo.TestType

SET @FN = REPLICATE('B',60)

EXEC dbo.Test_SP  @FullName = @FN
GO

--IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.table_types WHERE name = 'TestTableType' AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo'))
--  DROP TYPE dbo.TestTableType
--GO

--CREATE TYPE dbo.TestTableType AS TABLE (FullName dbo.TestType )
--GO

--EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule @name = 'TestTableType'; --TT_TestTableType_1BA066B0

--doesnt work until I drop and recreate that table type
DROP TYPE dbo.TestType_Old
GO
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't modify UDT after you have created. You can check this article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb522526(v=sql.105)

Comment: @ZekiGumus Thanks for response. Yes I know but I still *need* to do it :)

Comment: User-defined table types are "secretly" backed by an actual table, for metadata purposes. (You can see this table with `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(type_table_object_id) FROM sys.table_types WHERE name = 'TableType'`.) It can't be "refreshed" since that would amount to recreating the table. (No, `ALTER TABLE` won't work.) So the only solution is the one you already know: actually recreate the table. This can be painful (especially since all the dependencies need recreating), but you can optimize the scripting in various ways, either by querying the system views or using SMO/PowerShell.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for your response. I will look into the options you suggested.