# Drop a user defined data type

Tags: sql-server

I need to drop/add a user defined data type because I want to go from `varchar(10)` to `nvarchar(10)` but it is referenced in code.  How do I break the reference?

Comment: is it referenced in code or in DDL, meaning you have columns of this type?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383494/alter-user-defined-type-in-sql-server

Comment: It is referenced in stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get read of all the dependant objects first by converting them to a base type. If it's a column's table, alter the columns definition; with procedures, alter the procedure's definition.

Comment: I did this.  now it says I have stored procedures referencing the type so I can not change it.  I need to drop it and re-add.

Comment: Find the UDDT in SSMS object explorer, right-click on it and choose "view dependencies", it will show you all dependent objects.