# Typed table in SQL Server 2008 R2 cannot work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
 CREATE TYPE TagTable AS TABLE (Tag VARCHAR(50))

    declare @FilteredTags as TagTable   
    INSERT INTO @FilteredTags (Tag)
    SELECT data FROM ...
```

It used to work, but then I want to alter `Tag` from `VARCHAR(15)` to `VARCHAR(50)`, I get an error:

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure SearchNewsByTag, Line 3
>   Column, parameter, or variable #10: Cannot find data type TagTable.
>   Parameter or variable '@FilteredTags' has an invalid data type.
>
> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SearchNewsByTag, Line 36
>   Must declare the table variable "@FilteredTags".

I tried to restart all SQL Server services,  try to use other name like TagTable2, TagTable3...still no work. Compatibility level is 100

SOLUTION: RUN THE SCRIPT from http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2008/how-to-alter-a-uddt/ to regenerate the new UDDT.

Comment: Please post the line where you're altering the varchar length. Are you altering the type, are you trying to directly alter the table variable? More detail here, please.

Comment: It is working without an issue http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2add/3 I think the type is not available in the database can you check that

Comment: @JaazCole i didn't write any thing to alter the varchar length, i think SQL Server doesn't that feature.

Comment: @Surendra, how can i check if the table type is available. This is my first time to use user-defined table type. Thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383494/alter-user-defined-type-in-sql-server looks decent, i'll try and let you know then.

Comment: It seems like you already found the solution to your question. You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please take care about table types. They have many restrictions.

If I need to modify a table type, I always create a new version and modify all related codes.

So if you follow the following pattern, you will never have problem:

- create a new type with the proper access permission
- modify all code that use the old type to use only the new type
- a lot of test
- upload into the live environment
- wait two weeks
- drop the old table type

You cannot modify or drop a table type if it is in use.