# Change domain subtype in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a domain that is `DateDom36:char(18)`, but I need to change the subtype to `date`. I changed it in Erwin, but somehow I did not save the changes before I created them on the database. How can I get SQL to accept me changing the type to date?

Note: This is not for class credit.

Comment: I think it's the domain. We had to create a domain with that name, with the subtype being `date`, but I made it `char(18)`.

Comment: Hmm. I'm using MSSMS. So the data type for name is char(30), the data type for jobtype is char(1), but I'm trying to make the data type for hire date to be DateDom36 with a base type of date instead of char(18). Does that explain anything?

Comment: You created a user-defined type called `DateDom(36)` which is really a `char(18)` system type?  Again, the terms are killing me. What do you see in SSMS if you expand `Programmability > Types > User-Defined Data Types` in your database?

Comment: "the terms are killing me" sorry about that, and thanks for your patience. I'll check now. I made a typo, though, it's DateDom36, not DateDom(36). so instead of seeing something like char(30) in the `Data Type`, I see `DateDom36:char(18)`. DateDom36 is user defined.

Comment: @Yuck so under there, I see the data types I created, one of which is `dbo.DateDom36(char(36),null)

Answer (score 2):

Try running this in a query window while connected to your database:

```
DROP TYPE DateDom36;
GO
CREATE TYPE DateDom36 FROM date;
```

This is a WAG based on what you've written above.  The type name is very curious because you usually wouldn't want to use parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry, the parens around the 36 was a typo, those do not exist anywhere. would I just do `DateDob36] FROM date;' then?

Comment: I do need the 36 though, as it's my identifier in this project. So I would do DateDom36?

Comment: Yes, again see my edits. The brackets are optional, unless you're using special characters (like parens), spaces, etc.  You could write either `DateDom36` or `[DateDom36]`. It does not matter.

Comment: Ok, it says that I cannot drop this type because it's being reference by a table, and when I go to change it in the table, it says I have to drop the table and re-enter it, but is there a way to do that with `Alter`?

Comment: There isn't an `ALTER TYPE` statement, so it isn't a simple thing. While it's being used by a table I think you may be out of luck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383494/alter-user-defined-type-in-sql-server could offer some help.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help. I think I'm going to have to ask my professor.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure all your char(18) values can be converted to a date.

Second, remember that brute force always works.

Dump the database to a text file, edit the CREATE DOMAIN statement, and load the database.

When you edit the CREATE DOMAIN statement, edit the type, not the name.

Comment: MS SQL doesn't have a `CREATE DOMAIN` statement.  It's `CREATE TYPE` which has slightly different syntax and rules regarding how types (domains) are created and modified (i.e. they can't be modified).

Comment: *"they can't be modified"* Well, that's painful. And CREATE DOMAIN has been in standard SQL since at least 1992. (And this problem is exactly *why* it's been in there since at least 1992.)

Comment: @Yuck: Are you sure you can't edit a CREATE TYPE statement in a *text* file, then load the text? That seems really odd to me.

Comment: *Well, that's painful* - it can be, but I think the choice was made so that table structures wouldn't have to be updated whenever a user-defined type (domain) is altered. Not to defend their design choice, just that this seems the likely reason. In other RDBMS maybe domains are implemented differently. In MSSQL they're better thought of as system type aliases. To your second point, yes, you can obviously edit a SQL script in a text editor and run it again. I feel - as it seems so do you - that this is a little heavy handed when only the type needs to be dropped and recreated.