# SQL Server 2012 - Cannot drop User defined (table) type while there are no active dependencies

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-types

I have a User-defined type within which the size of one VARCHAR column needs to be increased. Altering the type is not possible because of dependencies (Stored procedures using that type). So, I tried the following:

This is the scenario:

1. Rename the type from `T_MyType` to `T_MyType_1`,
2. Ask Management Studio to build a creation script for type `T_MyType_1`,
3. Edit the script, remove the "`_1`" from the type name and increase size of one field, then run the script,
4. Run the procedure that caused the truncation problem (column length) and got a successful result (no truncation nor error messages),
5. Attempt to delete type `T_MyType_1` and got error stating that the type is being used by procedure ABC,
6. Search for `T_MyType_1` within the body of procedure ABC and *string not found*.

So, I'm stuck with a type defined that needs to be deleted.

### Edit

I believe this question is different to the proposed duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alter user defined type in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383494/alter-user-defined-type-in-sql-server)

Comment: @EzLo, not even close.

Comment: Try a quick [`sp_refreshsqlmodule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshsqlmodule-transact-sql) on the stored procedure.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, isn't that equivalent to right-click on **Stored Procedures** (Management Studio)? If yes, already tried it.

Comment: No, that's not the same thing at all. "Refresh" in Management Studio just means "please retrieve the list of these objects again from the server". It does not invoke `sp_refreshsqlmodule`.

Comment: hi, did you use `sp_rename` or just renamed the object from Object Explorer?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, YOU ARE THE MAN!!! As soon as I used that command with one SP, the `DROP TYPE` command changed the name of the dependent SP to another one. Used your command and the dependent procedure changed again. few more loops and eventually the drop type did its job. Thank you Sir!!!!!!

Comment: Feedback: you are welcome to add an explanation to questions (at the end!) about why a question is not the same as a proposed duplicate. However, for their to be a point to this edit, you need to explain _why_ they are different, not just that they are different. Proposed dups are, in the main, someone trying to help, so it is worth responding appropriately. Phrases like "read my question carefully" will be considered extraordinarily rude by native English speakers, and thus this is best avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming is a dangerous pastime because it doesn't mesh well with SQL Server's limited implementation of dependency tracking, and the deferred name resolution of stored procedures. I couldn't actually reproduce this specific scenario on SQL Server 2017 (dependencies were correctly tracked if the UDT is used in the procedure's body) so it's possible this case has been improved. Certainly, if you use the UDT as a *parameter* it actually detects the problem and gives an appropriate error message:

```
CREATE TYPE BadUdt FROM NVARCHAR(10);
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE AreUdtsBadThough(@T BadUdt) AS BEGIN
    RETURN;
END;
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'BadUdt', 'GoodUdt';
GO
CREATE TYPE BadUdt FROM NVARCHAR(20);
GO
EXEC AreUdtsBadThough NULL
```

> Msg 496, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AreUdtsBadThough, Line 6 [Batch
>   Start Line 16] The parameter "@T" is not the same type as the type it
>   was created with. Drop and recreate the module using a two-part name
>   for the type, or use sp_refreshsqlmodule to refresh its parameters
>   metadata.

Despite the name change, the parameter of `AreUdtsBadThough` is still linked to the old type by ID, which is why you can't drop that:

```
SELECT p.[name], t.[name]
FROM sys.parameters p
JOIN sys.types t ON p.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('AreUdtsBadThough')
```

```
+------+---------+
| name |  name   |
+------+---------+
| @T   | GoodUdt |
+------+---------+
```

The error helpfully describes the general solution for dependency problems: invoke [`sp_refreshsqlmodule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshsqlmodule-transact-sql), which forces the stored procedure (or function, or trigger, or view) to effectively be recompiled and the dependencies to be updated:

```
EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule 'AreUdtsBadThough'

SELECT p.[name], t.[name]
FROM sys.parameters p
JOIN sys.types t ON p.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('AreUdtsBadThough')
```

```
+------+--------+
| name |  name  |
+------+--------+
| @T   | BadUdt |
+------+--------+
```

And now `GoodUdt` has no dependencies anymore and can be dropped.

The problem of dependencies not always getting updated correctly (which is not restricted to renaming) has prompted some people to come up with more permanent solutions. Aaron Bertrand has an [article](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008) on automating the dependency refreshes for SQL Server 2008 (which should still work for later editions, even if it may do more work than necessary) due to improved dependency checks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not ever rename an object. This is generally not recommended and I know it may cause issues. Most probably this is the core of your problem and I suspect that there is some hidden mapping(s) behind all this.

In general: if an `ALTER` is not available, then a rename won't be useful.

I would suggest to find all dependencies, build required drop and create scripts and thus make sure everything is fine. All this could even be done with a script going through system tables extracting the very scripts you need. Another approach is to find the dependencies and Script them through Generate Scripts command, thus ensuring that the scripts will be generated in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Dependencies: That's exactly the point!!! There are none.

Comment: You wrote that the UDTT is used by a SP? I think it is still tied to the type, no matter you renamed it

Comment: See above the suggestion proposed by @JeroenMostert. It fixed the problem. Thanks anyway for your time and effort.