# How to alter user defined data types in SQL Server tables and SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement where I need to update UDDT

`UDDT : [dbo].[version_name]` which is basically of `varchar(5)` which I need to change it to `varchar(50)`.

Here UDDT is used in few tables and in the Stored Procedure.

**New Script**:

```
DROP TYPE [dbo].[version_name]

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[version_name] FROM [VARCHAR](50)
```

But I am not sure the above script will make sure all dependencies will be intact or not.

Any suggestion/help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why have you tagged both MySQL and SQL Server? Please stick to a single RDBMS. I think you will find if you attempt to carry out your script that it will fail citing dependencies. I believe you have to remove all dependencies before dropping a UUDT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alter user defined type in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1383494/1048425)

Comment: With that being said, my actual suggestion would be to move your database to a SQL Server database project (or similar), and leverage the tools that gives, Firstly, it gives you version control which is always a good idea, but more importantly in this case it allows you to do a comparison between your project and your database, which will automatically generate these kind of scripts for you, ensuring that all dependencies are dropped first then recreated.

Comment: +100 to GarethD's suggestion. You can "compile" a database project to find whether your changes cause any problems. Database projects are available in Azure Data Studio as well, which means you don't need to install SSDT/Visual Studio. With both ADS and SSDT, you can reverse-engineer the current database schema, *version it*, test your changes and when all is OK, either publish it to the target or do a schema compare to find the changes and apply what you want.

Comment: how I will know said uudt in the stored procedures will work as expected, as those are not showing in dependencies?
and btw i am doing in sql server only