# SQL Server 2012 : How to create a type with a check constraint?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I create a UDT of type varchar(8) which value should pass a check constraint?

I need that because that type + constraint will be reused in a few table and I'd like to avoid repetition like below.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1 (
    <some columns>
    , Comparison CHAR(4) NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT CHK_tRule_Comparison CHECK (Comparison IN (
        'Eq'
        , 'Diff'
        , 'Lt'
        , 'Lte'
        , 'Gt'
        , 'Gte'
        , 'Bgn'
        , 'BgnR'
        , 'End'
        , 'EndR'
    ))
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.T2 (
    <some columns>
    , Comparison CHAR(4) NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT CHK_tRule_Comparison CHECK (Comparison IN (
        'Eq'
        , 'Diff'
        , 'Lt'
        , 'Lte'
        , 'Gt'
        , 'Gte'
        , 'Bgn'
        , 'BgnR'
        , 'End'
        , 'EndR'
    ))
)


CREATE TABLE dbo.T3 (
    <some columns>
    , Comparison CHAR(4) NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT CHK_tRule_Comparison CHECK (Comparison IN (
        'Eq'
        , 'Diff'
        , 'Lt'
        , 'Lte'
        , 'Gt'
        , 'Gte'
        , 'Bgn'
        , 'BgnR'
        , 'End'
        , 'EndR'
    ))
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to add a check constraint to a UDT and I would not recommend that you use a UDT at all. There is no end to the grief if you ever need to [change it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/349107/569436).

Create a table `RuleComparison` and add a foreign key constraint on the `Comparison` column.

```
create table RuleComparison
(
  Value char(4) primary key
)

insert into RuleComparison
values ('Eq'),
       ('Diff'),
       ('Lt'),
       ('Lte'),
       ('Gt'),
       ('Gte'),
       ('Bgn'),
       ('BgnR'),
       ('End'),
       ('EndR')

create table T1
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Comparison char(4) references RuleComparison(Value)
)
```

Comment: +1 Good article on the topic [T-SQL UDTs. (Huh!) What are they good for?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2010/08/25/t-sql-udts-what-are-they-good-for.aspx) (Not much)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom data type. Then you create a rule using the CREATE RULE statement, where you specify the variable values that your column can accept. And through the SP_BINDRULE (system procedure), specify 'the name of the created role' and 'the name of the user type' (NOTE: the Rules do not apply to values already created in the database)
`

```
CREATE TYPE ChekNok 
FROM varchar(5)
GO

CREATE RULE RulNok
AS
@per in ('fd','dff')
GO

EXEC SP_bindrule 'RulNok', 'ChekNok'
`
```